# How can I use declared variables of a function outside the function but keeping their values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, scope, simplemodal, template-literals

I have this array of objects

```js
const GALLERY = [
{
    color: "red",
    titulo: "Stuff"
},
{
    color: "pink",
    titulo: "Thing"
},
{
    color: "green",
    titulo: "Something"
}
];
```

and these functions with template literals

```js
function galTemplate(gal) {
    let modalBtn = gal.color + "-btn";
    return `
    <div class="content-entry" id="${modalBtn}">
        <div href="" style="background-color: ${gal.color};"></div>
        <p class="gallery-entry-titulo">${gal.titulo}</p>
    </div>
    `
}

function galModal(modal) {
    let modalModal = modal.color + "-modal";
    return `
    <div class="popup-bg" id="${modalModal}">
      <div class="entry-popup">
        <div style="background-color: ${modal.color};></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    `
}
```

The situation is that I want to use the variables modalBtn and modaModal with their values to create a simple modal function that looks like this

```js
modalBtn.onclick = function() {
    modalModal.style.display = "block";
}
```

Of course, this is an example of the real project.
This is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/afxcrush/pen/LYbpgqm) of the complete example for best comprehension

Comment: Template Literals are really just Strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Variables

You can declare variables outside the scope of a function with the keyword `var` like this:

```js
var my_global = 1;
function do_something_with_global() {
    console.log(my_global++);
}
do_something_with_global(); // will print: 1
console.log(my_global); // will print: 2
```

They will live in the global space so you can access them from everywhere. This is generally a bad design choice because this stuff will not be garbage collected (in a function-scope the memory will be freed once it is executed).

Besides, globals can be modified from everywhere now, so you don't want that either. There could be hard-to-spot bugs when you accidentially override the variables, too.

Just be aware of this. You may also want to read this here: https://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices

### Possible solution based on your aim

I would probably choose a different way of creating the elements and rendering them  in one go (i.e. `createElement()` and then add the listeners and modals in sequence).

However, I wanted to change as few as possible so that you can work with it more easily.

You could and probably should also just toggle a CSS class instead of modifying the individual attributes.

How about the following:

```js
const GALLERY = [{
    color: 'red',
    titulo: 'Stuff'
  },
  {
    color: 'pink',
    titulo: 'Thing'
  },
  {
    color: 'green',
    titulo: 'Something'
  }
];

function galTemplate(gal) {
  let modalBtn = gal.color + '-btn';
  return `
    <div class="content-entry" id="${modalBtn}">
        <div href="" style="background-color: ${gal.color};"></div>
        <p class="gallery-entry-titulo">${gal.titulo}</p>
    </div>
    `;
}

function galModal(modal) {
  let modalModal = modal.color + '-modal';
  return `
    <div class="popup-bg" id="${modalModal}">
      <div class="entry-popup">
        <div style="background-color: ${modal.color};"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    `;
}

function addClickListeners(gal) {
  let btnId = gal.color + '-btn';
  let modalId = gal.color + '-modal';
  let elBtn = document.getElementById(btnId);
  let elModal = document.getElementById(modalId);
  elBtn.onclick = function() {
    console.log('click: btn: ' + this.id + ', modal: ' + elModal.id);
    elModal.classList.toggle('show-popup');
  }
  /* to dispose the popup on click */
  elModal.onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle('show-popup');
  }
  /* --- */
}

document.getElementById("my-content").innerHTML = `
  <div class="content">
    ${GALLERY.map(galTemplate).join('')}
  </div>
  ${GALLERY.map(galModal).join('')}
`;
GALLERY.map(addClickListeners);
```

```css
body {
  background: #01235f;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 0px;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}

.content-entry {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content-entry div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.gallery-entry-titulo {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -30%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup-bg {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}

.show-popup {
  display: block;
}

.entry-popup {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 80%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 60px;
}

.entry-popup div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="my-content"></div>
```

Comment: Ok, this is close to what I want to achieve, but for some reason only the first element activate the modal, the pink and green doesn't.

Comment: @AfxCrush Yeah, but the clicks work. See the logs from the console. The problem is somewhere different.

Comment: @AfxCrush When you inspect the DOM you can see that the modals are in a parent-child-relationship in other words they are nested. If you fix the DOM it should just work fine I suppose.

Comment: @AfxCrush You forgot to close a quote ... this resulted in html closing the div early so it stacked. I fixed it and edited my solution.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you very much <3 I'm gonna work with your code and try to solve the DOM error

Comment: @AfxCrush No big deal. Btw I have fixed it already :) - you can run the snippet and see if this is what you had in mind. If you want to support me, please mark the answer as accepted and hit the upvote button.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, we have something called `Global Variables`. We can take advantage of this similar to the piece of code below:

```js
let global_var;
function set_var(){
    global_var = "Hello"
}
set_var();
console.log(global_var);
```

Comment: Yes, already tried that and also giving undefined values, but not working in this case. Thank you anyway